# ST_Snap alternative to not lose time dimension when splitting a Linestring

Tags: postgis, linear-referencing

In order to compute the distance of a given track at different periodicity (daily, weekly ..),
I am using `ST_Split` to split the track at different point in time and compute the length for each splitted track.

As recommended, I am using `ST_Split` with `ST_Snap` to improve the robustness of the split.

The problem is that with `ST_Snap`, I lose the M dimension of my linestring (time here).

For now my solution to find the start and end of each splitted track is to use `ST_InterpolatePoint` to interpolate them from the original track, which don't work well when multiple points in track have the same position.

Do you know alternative to `ST_Snap` to not lose the time?

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS has a [set of linear reference functions](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Linear_Referencing) specifically made for this purpose.

Look at

- `ST_LineSubstring` to follow your current workflow, or
- `ST_LocateBetweenElevations` to work directly with the `M` values